# How to merge two columns based on a certain "primay key" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes:

```
id      Name     CTI
 1      abc       123
 2      vbfd      456
 3      ewrwe     789 
 4      ewr       4w4
 4      qweqw     434
 4      poitg     4311
 5      edfsdf    113
 5      wqeweqw   314
```

and

```
 id      Name     MAX
 1      abc       1323
 2      vbfd      45634
 3      ewrwe     789343
 4      ewr       4w4324
 4      qweqw     434324
 4      poitg     43112342
 5      edfsdf    113324
 5      wqeweqw   3142342
```

I want to add the CTI column to the second dataframe.
Basically I want,

```
id      Name     MAX          CTI
 1      abc       1323        123
 2      vbfd      45634       456
 3      ewrwe     789343      789 
 4      ewr       4w4324      4w4
 4      qweqw     434324      434
 4      poitg     43112342    4311
 5      edfsdf    113324      113
 5      wqeweqw   3142342     314
```

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2['CTI']=df1['CTI']
```

This create a new column in df2 DataFrame with values of df1 CTI field.

assuming df2:

```
 id      Name     MAX
 1      abc       1323
 2      vbfd      45634
 3      ewrwe     789343
 4      ewr       4w4324
 4      qweqw     434324
 4      poitg     43112342
 5      edfsdf    113324
 5      wqeweqw   3142342
```

and df1:

```
id      Name     CTI
 1      abc       123
 2      vbfd      456
 3      ewrwe     789 
 4      ewr       4w4
 4      qweqw     434
 4      poitg     4311
 5      edfsdf    113
 5      wqeweqw   314
```

After apply `df2['CTI']=df1['CTI']`,df2 is the output required:

```
id      Name     MAX          CTI
 1      abc       1323        123
 2      vbfd      45634       456
 3      ewrwe     789343      789 
 4      ewr       4w4324      4w4
 4      qweqw     434324      434
 4      poitg     43112342    4311
 5      edfsdf    113324      113
 5      wqeweqw   3142342     314
```

Answer (score 0):

I need the names of the df's but let's make two up, df1 and df2.

```
df2['CTI'] = df1['CTI']
```

**this should do it**

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key is important you can use this syntax which must use `how` with `inner` value

```
combined_df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'inner', on = ['id'])
```

This will join the fields that are not present in df2 and are present in df1 with all fields of d2 based on the equality of `id`.